# Where is the default value of the organizationName is coming from in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

sbt defines the `organizationName` setting as `SettingKey[String]` (see [Keys](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/517cbf6d2d7239032daf2b4d0b312aebc7662341/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L289)). When starting an sbt build in an empty directory, one can inspect the default value of `organizationName`:

```
> inspect organizationName
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = default
[info] Description:
[info]  Organization full/formal name.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/bene/workspace/sbt/test/}test/*:organizationName
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:1174
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:organization
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:projectInfo
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:organizationName
[info]  {.}/*:organizationName
[info]  */*:organizationName
```

So the `organizationName` setting defaults to "default". Now the question is, where is the default value coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may not be completely obvious, all the information is already there. The sbt output gives us a first hint:

```
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:1174
```

In [line 1174 in Default.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1174) we can see, that `organizationName` falls back to the value of `organization`. Inspecting the `organization` setting gives us the next hint:

```
> inspect organization
[info] Setting: java.lang.String = default
[info] Description:
[info]  Organization/group ID.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/bene/workspace/sbt/test/}test/*:organization
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:1173
[info]  (sbt.Build) Build.scala:58
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:normalizedName
[info]  *:thisProject
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:organizationName
[info]  *:projectId
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:organization
[info]  {.}/*:organization
[info]  */*:organization
```

Finally, in [Build.scala:58](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Build.scala#L62) we can find the mapping from a missing organization to `"default"`.